# How to clean application history in hadoop yarn?

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn

After applications finished on yarn, a great amount application history will be shown in yarn.

Both in web-ui `http://localhost:8088/cluster` and command line `yarn application -list -appStates FINISHED`

How can I clean these history? Or where does yarn store these history information?

Restart RM,NM does not clean these history.

Delete the logs in local file system ${YARN_LOG_DIR}/userlogs does not clean these history.

Delete the logs' directory/files in hdfs:///tmp/logs/username/logs does not clean these history.

Hadoop version: 2.7.7

Answer (score 3):

If you've enabled log-aggregation, you can set `yarn.log-aggregation.retain-seconds` to a reasonable value (like a day or a week depending on how many jobs you run) to have YARN purge jobs on a continual basis.

Otherwise set `yarn.nodemanager.log.retain-seconds` to determine how long you want to keep logs.

You can also disable persistence on restarts by setting `yarn.resourcemanager.recovery.enabled` to `false` in your yarn-site.xml.

Refer to [yarn-default.xml](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.7/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-common/yarn-default.xml) for all the log configurables in YARN and [ResourceManager Restart](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/ResourceManagerRestart.html) for more information on persistence.

Answer (score -1):

Oh, I've found the solution.

`yarn resourcemanager -format-state-store`

and restart the cluster.

But still don't know where yarn store these history, in ZK?

Comment: The state store keeps track of all the applications YARN is running and has run.  Doing this on a running cluster is not a good idea.